# SQL Server 2008 R2 Database Isolation Change

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How can i change my database isolation to read uncommitted in SQL server 2008 R2, Can someone tell me the exact process and how should I can achieve this?

Comment: I hope you are aware of the implications of doing this. Potentially returning phantom data, duplicate data, etc to your clients. If you want to resolve blocking issues, look into snapshot isolation first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to achive this:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173763.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please see MSDN [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173763(v=sql.105).aspx) for the same.